# How can you factor out branching from tight loop?

Tags: c++, performance, theory

My question is: How can I add features to my processing loop without the overhead of checking the true/falseness of the user settings to navigate the branches? The settings are the same for all iterations on the loop. Do modern processors with branch prediction make this unnecessary?

My programs over follow this pattern:

1. User adjusts settings, checkboxes, sliders, numerical entries.
2. Data is processed when an update is triggered

   1. Apply settings to local variables
   2. Run loop over a large dataset

      - add if statements to bypass unused code from the user settings.
      - return from loop
   3. return transformed data

How can you template or inline out all permutations ahead of time?

example:

```
bool setting1 = true;
bool setting2 = false;
vector<float> data;

for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
    data.push_back(i);

for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    if (setting1)
    {
       doStuff(data[i]);
       ....
    }
    if (setting2)
    {
       doMoreStuff(data[i]);
       .....
    }

    .... //etc
}
```

I know this is a silly example. But I'd like to know what pattern scales when there are lots of branches.

Comment: Why do you ask? Is there a performance problem with your loop? Have you measured? (If not, write the code that's easiest to maintain, and optimize it when profiling shows you need to, using profiling as a guide which optimizations are best.)

Comment: Maybe you should opt for cleanliness instead of performance first. Instead of setting you could have a `vector` with `std::functionS` that need to be performed on an iteration depending on the settings. In other languages that would be called `hooks`. It's very easy to maintain and a lot easier to read.

Comment: I'm satisfied with the feedback.

Comment: Bonus Points if anyone can "templatize" the branch dispatching function. eg. if (setting1) loop<1>(); else loop<0>();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use templates for the main loop.

```
template <bool A, bool B>
void loop() {
  while (1) {
      if (A) // will get compiled out if A == false
      {
         doStuff(data[i]);
         ....
      }
      if (B)
      {
         doMoreStuff(data[i]);
         .....
      }

      .... //etc
  }
}
```

When you change settings: (you could probably make this less code)

```
if (setting1) {
  if (setting2)
    loop<1,1>;
  else 
    loop<1,0>;
}
else {
  if (setting2)
    loop<0,1>;
  else 
    loop<0,0>;
}
```

You want to stay in loop() until settings change.

**This should be used with care as it can lead to bloat.**

---

### Profiled the answers (G++ O2 optimization):

```
 %Time
 46.15      0.84     0.84                             fb() (blackbear)
 38.37      1.53     0.69                             fa() (OP)
 16.13      1.82     0.29                             fc() (pubby8)
```

Comment: The only "bloat" created through this would be the proliferation of loops - which is exactly what the OP wanted. The whole template-magic is pure compile-time, and should be fully eliminated after compilation.

Comment: @sbi if you have 16 settings you suddenly have 256 functions being created. It can lead to worse cache locality if you're not careful.

Comment: Of course, but my point is that this is the same if those functions are written by hand. Templates have nothing to do with it, except that they relieve you from having to write and maintain 256 very similar functions manually.

Comment: I re-read the second part. That answers how to dispatch the function factored out of the loop. Thanks.

Comment: this should do the job, I used a similar structure for image manipulation.

Comment: Why on earth would you use templates, rather than just different functions?  The key is simply to have separate loops for each combination of settings, and hoist the tests out of the loop.

Comment: This is some truly awkward code, and deserves care and caution in use. Of course, that is usually true of optimized code. But: I don't really like this approach; it leads to some really gnarly combinatorical explosion of possibilities.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The template solution has the advantage that it will generate, from the same code, all those "separate loops for each combination of settings", which can easily be a lot.

Comment: @sbi Since all of the loops are different, the template solution doesn't buy you anything.  It's just excess complexity.

Comment: @JamesKanze: There seems to be a misunderstanding somewhere. The way I understand this answer, you write a single function template, from which all the different functions are generated.

Comment: @sbi Except that each generated function is completely different, because at the top level, you have a series of `if`s based on the template argument.  So you end up having to write each function manually anyway.

Comment: @JamesKanze: There must be a serious misunderstanding here, but I don't see any effort from you to clear this up. All I see is repeated assertions that you are right and I am wrong. Since there is nothing to learn from me here, I give up this discussion. HAND.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't understand what you are arguing. You have to write 2 functions opposed to 1, but the optimization benefits of doing so is worth it.

Comment: @Pubby8 You have to write as many loops as there are combinations of settings.  Whether they are all in the same function, or in as many different functions, is really irrelevant; I would tend to make a lot of little functions, because that's easier to read, but it certainly doesn't affect the optimization.

Comment: @JamesKanze: From this it seems obvious that either you or I have misunderstood this answer. Judging from Pubby8's reaction I suppose it's you.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, unless the operations are incredibly cheap compared to the cost of an iteration of the loop (branches + loop overhead), simply don't worry about it and do whatever is most readable. Premature optimisation is the root of much evil; don't just assume things will be slow, do some profiling so that you *know*.

If you do find yourself genuinely spending more time iterating than doing useful work - that is, your overhead is too high - you need to find a sensible way to reduce the overhead; so, to select between different loop bodies/implementations optimised for particular combinations of inputs.

Factoring the conditions out of the loop, to make multiple loops, might initially seem like a good idea, however if most of the settings are mostly enabled and your actual operations are cheap enough to make the overhead an issue at all, you may find the performance largely unchanged - each of the new loops has a per-iteration cost!

If that is the case, a way forward might be to use templates or other means to instantiate variants of the loop body for the most common combinations of inputs, select at a high level between loops calling those when a suitable one is available, and fall back to the generic case when it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the overhead this way (supposing settingx doesn't affect settingy):

```
if(setting1) {
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
        // ...
    }
}

if(setting3) {
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
        // ...
    }
}

if(setting3) {
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But, in my opinion, the best solution is keeping your code. Today's branch prediction units are very powerful, and considering that you'll loop many thousands of times with every branch having the same result, you can afford a few cycles of warm up ;)

**EDIT:**
I compared our approaches to the problem with a simple console program ([sources](http://pastebin.com/CF6it5UL), it's c# though). The loop is executed 1000000 times and I used trigonometrical functions together with double precision floating point operations. Test 2 is the solution I showed above, and the three letters are the value of setting1, setting2 and setting3.
Results are:

```
test 1 - fft: 13974 ms
test 2 - fft: 14106 ms

test 1 - tft: 27728 ms
test 2 - tft: 28081 ms

test 1 - ttt: 41833 ms
test 2 - ttt: 41982 ms
```

I also did a test run with all three test functions empty to prove loop and calling overhead is minimal:

```
test 1 - fft: 4 ms
test 2 - fft: 4 ms

test 1 - tft: 8 ms
test 2 - tft: 8 ms

test 1 - ttt: 12 ms
test 2 - ttt: 12 ms
```

Effectively, **my solution is about 1% slower**. The second point of my answer, though is proven to be correct: loop overhead is completely trascurable.

Comment: that's *very bad* for memory locality

Comment: @yi_H: well, while you're right, the downvote isn't fair, since I've answered the OP's question correctly, "How can I add features to my processing loop _without the overhead of checking the true/falseness of the user settings_ to navigate the branches"

Comment: @BlackBear: The downvote is mine. IMO the sentence "Do modern processors with branch prediction make this unnecessary?" makes it abundantly clear that this is about _performance_ overhead, and your answers impairs performance in one of the worst possible ways.

Comment: @sbi: I still don't get it, perhaps I didn't explained well. Basically my answer is: "Do modern processors with branch prediction make this unnecessary?" -> "yes". I get that the snippet I provided is quite dumb though :)

Comment: The only mistake here is not combining combinations of settings. Failting to do that may result in looping over all the data multiple times. However, if the number of combinations is too large the code becomes unmanageable with a loop for each combination of settings.

Comment: I added an upvote, because this is the correct answer.  Hoist all of the tests out of the loop, and use as many loops as there are combinations of settings.  As for locality: this has better locality than the initial loop, since each of the loops are smaller.

Comment: Please check with C or C++. .NET VM JIT does optimizations, unless I am badly mistaken.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: my vs has only C# installed (school issues...). If you would like to do it for me, I'll post the results :)

Comment: C#? Are you even serious? A C++ optimizer will most certainly generate quite different code from a C# optimizer.

Comment: @BlackBear: Oh, wait a minute. Maybe I (and yi_H) misunderstood your code. So are those three loops this three snippets of code with one loop each or is it one snippet with three loops one after the other?

Comment: @sbi: It's a single snippet with the loops one after the other.

Comment: @BlackBear: Then, as yi_H, this plays bad with caching.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the dataset is known at compile time, then the compiler can potentially perform:

- loop unrolling

If it is a mathematical operation

- vectorization can come into play

You can also do the logic inside-out:

```
if (epic-setting)
{
//massive for loop
}
```

It *is* bad for memory locality, as one person said.

Branch prediction will help you a good deal, if and only if the cost of the missed branch is less than the speedup given (for a large dataset, it should help, not hurt).

If your data operation is fully parallel, ie, you are running SIMD, you could investigate threading out the operations: e.g., open up 3 threads, and have all 3 take the `i % t` operation, `t` being the thread index, `i` being the data index. (You can partition the data different ways). For a large enough data set, presuming you don't have synch operations, you will see a linear speedup.

If you are writing this for a specialized system, e.g., an industrial computer with a given CPU, and you can assume you will always have that CPU, you can optimize much more heavily for what that CPU can support. Things like exact cache size, depth of pipeline, etc, can all be coded in. Unless you can assume that, it's sketchy to try and assume on those counts.